# Data saving management in text file using java

Tags: android

I wrote an android application which collect data from sensors and saves the collected data in a text file for plotting and for other purpose after that, 
the problem is to save the collected data in specific format into text file
for example: I need to save the data inside text file as following format:

> 1,34
>
> 2,40
>
> 3,56
>
> 4,66
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .

... and so on.

But the data is stored with me as the following:

> 1,342 403 564 66

which this is the problem.

The writing function looks like this:

```
 public void writing_in_file_1(){
     try{
         //file_1.createNewFile();
         fw  = new FileWriter(file_1, true);
         bw  = new BufferedWriter(fw);
         out = new PrintWriter(bw);
         out.append(String.valueOf(time + "\t "+currentReading ) );
         out.append("\n");
         //out.append(String.valueOf(current_reading_list));
         out.flush();
         Toast.makeText(
                   this,
                   "Done writing SD 'specific text file'",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
             .show();
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally {
             try {
                 bw.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `BufferedWriter.newLine()` method here:

```
  BufferedWriter buf = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(Filename, true)); 
  buf.append(text);
  buf.newLine();
  buf.close();
```

Also, my guess is you don't really need the `PrinterWriter` class there.

Comment: i tried as you motioned but the out put lokks like :

5000.0

1 5000.0
2 5000.0
3 5000.0
4 5000.0
5 5000.0
6 5000.0
7 1000.0
8 1000.0
9 5000.0
10 5000.0
11 1000.0
12 5000.0

Comment: my code was right and its running correctly, the problem was in the notepad opner, i checked that using csv file